# Can i move to specific position of an animation on button click instead of animating my mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a morphed 3D mesh which i can load using `threejs`. After loading the model, i can start the animation clips.

But i dont want to just run the animation, i want to move to a specific position in the animation on button click. For example, i have an animation clip of 1 minutes long. If user press a button, i want to morph the geometry in a way so that it resembles the geometry when the animation clip is at 30 seconds.

Is there any way to do it in `threejs` or is there any other approach you can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do it in threejs or is there any other approach you can suggest?

Yes, I think this should be possible. When you playback the animation clip with an instance of `AnimationAction`, you can immediately pause it and then set the `time` property to the desired value. The code looks like so:

```
  const clipAction = mixer.clipAction( clip );
  clipAction.play();
  clipAction.paused = true;
  clipAction.time = 0.5;
```

The approach is demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/w6catxfh/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if your animation can be time parameterised. Consider two methods of making a cube move up. On the one hand, you can simply tell the cube to move up from its current position by a certain amount each animation loop:

```
var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.position.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };
```

Another way to do the same animation is to describe the cube's position as a function of time:

```
var currentTime = 0;

var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.position.y = 0.01 * currentTime;
                currentTime += 1;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };
```

The visual effect is the same, but you can change the `currentTime` variable to jump around on the animation 'timeline'.